# Transform C# function to PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I need to transform this encryption function developed in C# to PHP. Thank you in advance.

```
private static byte[] Encrypt3DES(string codigoCliente, byte[] key)
{
    var codigoClienteBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codigoCliente);
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] SALT = new byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
 
    tdes.BlockSize = 64;
    tdes.KeySize = 192;
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    tdes.IV = SALT;
    tdes.Key = key;
 
    var cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
 
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(codigoClienteBytes, 0, codigoClienteBytes.Length);
 
    tdes.Clear();
    return resultArray;
}
```

I've tried something like this in PHP but the string result is the same but not the same length.

```
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key)
{
    // Se cifra
    $l = ceil(strlen($message) / 8) * 8;
    return encodeBase64(
         openssl_encrypt($message . str_repeat("\0", $l - strlen($message)),
         'des-ede3-cbc', 
         $key, 
         OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, 
         "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a problem? A BASE64-encoded string can be padded to a certain length *without* altering its payload. When you decode the BASE64 string do you get the same bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very nearby to get the correct ciphertext in PHP.

Using below code will generate the same result as your C# function.

**Security warning: 3DES (Triple DES) is outdated and should be substituted with modern algorithms like AES.**

code:

```
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key)
{
    $method = 'des-ede3-cbc';
    if (strlen($message) % 8) {
        $message = str_pad($message, strlen($message) + 8 - strlen($message) % 8, "\0");
    }
    $iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($message, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv); //Force zero padding.
    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
```

Comment: The implementation is ok!!. Now I get the same values ​​as with the C# function. Thanks a lot.